# Can I mount docker host directory as copy on write/overlay?

Tags: docker

I'd like to mount a host directory in docker that on the outside is actually read/only.  But I'd like it to appear inside the container as read/write.

So that files/directories can be written to but not changed on the outside. Is this possible using some kind of overlay process?

Comment: You want to do be able to mount the volume at container runtime, `COPY`ing the directory during image creation isn't an option?

Comment: In the end that's what I did.

Comment: I'm looking to do the same, and `COPY` isn't ideal in my case as the data is over 40gb.

Comment: I needed to do on CoreOS to build kernel modules.  But I wanted the docker container to see everything from the host and create a new modules.conf with everything populated.  I had to copy in the end.  But the accepted answer worked for me if it wasn't the kernel module directory.  It doesn't actually work for the kernel module directory.

Comment: A colleague pointed out that Podman has an `:O` option when mounting volumes, which stands for [Overlay Volume Mount](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-run.1.html#volume-v-source-volume-host-dir-container-dir-options).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Edit: Check @javabrett's comment:

> Upvoted despite this solution having a sunset. See answer regarding overlay-upperdir-on-overlay being disabled on 4.8 kernels and newer.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50917037/644504

---

This is what I do:

**On the host:**

Load the directory as read only.

```
docker run --privileged -v /path/on/host:/path/on/client-read-only:ro -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

**On the client:**

On the client use OverlayFS over the read-only directory mounted from the host.

```
mount -t overlayfs none -o lowerdir=/path/on/client-read-only,upperdir=/path/on/client /path/on/client
```

Then use `/path/on/client` to read/write the files.

**Edit**: if you have a 3.18+ kernel on your host, you may prefer using this on the client:

```
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/path/on/client-read-only,upperdir=/path/on/client,workdir=/path/on/client-workdir /path/on/client
```

Which isn't `overlayfs`. With `overlayfs` I had an issue regarding being unable to use `rm`. `overlay` solved this problem for me.

Comment: I've been trying to use this solution, but I get an error: "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on overlay, missing codepage or helper program, or other error (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program) In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try  dmesg | tail  or so". Is there any module or restrictions to this solution?

Comment: I have got the same issue as @GustavoMeira , ubuntu 14.04 host with 4.2 kernel and docker 1.11.

Comment: RE: "wrong fs type, bad option" I found this was because my upperdir was provided by aufs (cf "stat -f /path/to/lowerdir" and note the "type"). I worked around this by creating a new tmpfs mount to hold my changes: "mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp/overlay && mkdir -p /tmp/overlay/{upper,work}" and then use those.

Comment: what happens with the mounted fs when the container exits?

Comment: @Woxxy: Can you comment on which capabilities are required for the mount? It seems that `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` is insufficient.

Comment: @RobM, thanks! This was very useful. This should be added to the answer. I've been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: When i try to execute this in my container, i get "mount: permission denied".

Comment: @MatthiasLohr you need to run with `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` but as mentioned above this might not be sufficient.

Comment: Upvoted despite this solution having a sunset, see anwser regarding overlay-upperdir-on-overlay being disabled on `4.8` kernels and newer.

Answer (score 29):

You can do this without running privileged containers, and without any other 3rd party tools, using the local volume driver. The local volume driver will pass any options to the mount syscall, so anything you can do with mount you can do as a volume in docker. The only prerequisite is that you create the overlay directories in advance and clean them up yourself.

First, lets create the directories and some read only data:

```
$ mkdir -p {ro-data,upper1,upper2,upper3,work1,work2,work3}

$ ls
ro-data  upper1  upper2  upper3  work1  work2  work3

$ vi ro-data/data.txt

$ cat ro-data/data.txt
This is a data file.
It should be read-only on the host upper dir.
```

Next, lets create a named volume with the overlay options and run a container with it:

```
$ docker volume create --driver local --opt type=overlay \
  --opt o=lowerdir=${PWD}/ro-data,upperdir=${PWD}/upper1,workdir=${PWD}/work1 \
  --opt device=overlay overlay1
overlay1

$ docker container run -d --rm -v overlay1:/data --name cont1 busybox tail -f /dev/null
a6269cb6c68469aa4f57aae554c5f0823f1103715334b3719c5567abc7d55daa
```

Then, lets do the same with a `--mount` option to run, which gets slightly more complicated because of the nested comma separated strings. Escaped quotes works around that:

```
$ docker run -d --rm \
  --mount type=volume,dst=/data,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=overlay,\"volume-opt=o=lowerdir=${PWD}/ro-data,upperdir=${PWD}/upper2,workdir=${PWD}/work2\",volume-opt=device=overlay \
  --name cont2 busybox tail -f /dev/null
7329ae4ba4046782166b045611ecccb129f5e557df7eb4da95ec9063a0fe234e
```

Finally, let's us a compose file:

```
$ vi docker-compose.yml

$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

volumes:
  overlay3:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: overlay
      o: lowerdir=${PWD}/ro-data,upperdir=${PWD}/upper3,workdir=${PWD}/work3
      device: overlay

services:
  overlay3:
    image: busybox
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    container_name: cont3
    volumes:
    - overlay3:/data

$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "vol-overlay_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "vol-overlay_overlay3" with local driver
Creating cont3 ... done
```

Everything is running, lets verify the data file is there:

```
$ docker exec cont1 ls -l /data
total 4
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000            67 Nov  8 16:29 data.txt

$ docker exec cont2 ls -l /data
total 4
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000            67 Nov  8 16:29 data.txt

$ docker exec cont3 ls -l /data
total 4
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000            67 Nov  8 16:29 data.txt
```

Next, we can make some changes to the directory in container 1, and delete the file in container 2:

```
$ echo "container 1 adds lines" | docker exec -i cont1 tee -a /data/data.txt
container 1 adds lines

$ echo "writing to another file" | docker exec -i cont1 tee -a /data/container1.txt
writing to another file

[11:48:30] [bmitch@bmitch-asusr556l:~/data/docker/test/vol-overlay] [master]
$ docker exec cont2 rm /data/data.txt
```

Verify each container see's the changes, or lack thereof:

```
$ docker exec cont1 ls -l /data
total 8
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            24 Nov  8 16:48 container1.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000            90 Nov  8 16:47 data.txt

$ docker exec cont2 ls -l /data
total 0

$ docker exec cont3 ls -l /data
total 4
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000            67 Nov  8 16:29 data.txt

$ docker exec cont1 cat /data/data.txt
This is a data file.
It should be read-only on the host upper dir.
container 1 adds lines

$ docker exec cont3 cat /data/data.txt
This is a data file.
It should be read-only on the host upper dir.
```

And show the host directory is unchanged:

```
$ ls -l ro-data
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 bmitch bmitch 67 Nov  8 11:29 data.txt

$ cat ro-data/data.txt
This is a data file.
It should be read-only on the host upper dir.
```

The changes were all made only to the upper directories:

```
$ ls -l upper*
upper1:
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   24 Nov  8 11:48 container1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 bmitch bmitch 90 Nov  8 11:47 data.txt

upper2:
total 0
c--------- 1 root root 0, 0 Nov  8 11:48 data.txt

upper3:
total 0
```

After removing the containers and volumes, you'll need to manually remove the upper directories. Just as docker doesn't create them for you, it doesn't delete them either, exactly the same as if you ran the mount command yourself.

Answer (score 12):

Not an option anymore from inside the container (possibly because overlay-over-overlay is disabled in ~ [4.4 kernels](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1629509))

```
$ uname -a && \
  docker run --privileged --rm debian:latest sh -c "mkdir upper lower work merged && mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=lower,upperdir=upper,workdir=work merged/; dmesg|tail -1"


Linux preprod 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1 (2018-05-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on overlay,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

[288426.860631] overlayfs: filesystem on 'upper' not supported as upperdir
```

**ANYWAY**
An alternative is to create the overlay on the **host** and bind it to the guest:

```
$ mkdir upper lower work merged && \
  touch upper/up lower/low && \
  sudo mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=lower,upperdir=upper,workdir=work merged/ && \
  docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/merged:/tmp/merged debian:latest sh -c "touch /tmp/merged/new-from-container"
```

`$ ls upper/ lower/ merged/`

```
lower/:
low

merged/:
low  new-from-container  up

upper/:
new-from-container  up
```

Answer (score 5):

This is possible if you avoid setting upperdir to a local dir (ie already an overlay). 
But you can use tmpfs instead (tested on kernel 4.9):

```
# On the host to run the container
docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -i -t -v ~/host-folder-to-mount:/root/folder-ro:ro ubuntu

# Inside the container
# Need to create the upper and work dirs inside a tmpfs.
mkdir -p /tmp/overlay && \
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp/overlay && \
mkdir -p /tmp/overlay/{upper,work} && \
mkdir -p /root/folder && \
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/root/folder-ro,upperdir=/tmp/overlay/upper,workdir=/tmp/overlay/work /root/folder
```

All credits goes to https://gist.github.com/detunized/7c8fc4c37b49c5475e68ef9574587eee

Comment: This was incredibly simple (compared to other answers) and "just worked", even on Docker for Windows 4.11.1/84025 (usually lots of issues with doing Linux manipulation on a Windows host).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to see whether your filesystem support overlayfs or not; and it can be verified with

```
  $> grep overlayfs /proc/filesystems
  $> overlayfs overlay
```

If so, then I would recommend you to create overlayfs in host machine and mount the merge directory to the Docker container so that you can manage things from the host machine rather than some on host and some on Docker container.

I followed the following steps to achieve this: Let me take an example; I have source-code and I want to build that for multiple platforms like **i386, x86_64 and amd64**; The source-code will remain same for all platform; where as the executable (.obj and exe) of each platform will differ; so we need executable in each specific platform directory

```
 sudo  mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/home/viswesn/source-code,upperdir=/home/viswesn/i386_executable,workdir=/i386 /home/viswesn/i386_merged

 sudo  mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/home/viswesn/source-code,upperdir=/home/viswesn/x86_64_executable,workdir=/x86_64 /home/viswesn/x86_64_merged
```

It says, any object files or executable created out of source files will remain in /home/viswesn/X_executable directory and source code will remain in /home/viswesn/source-code; where as /home/viswesn/X_merged/ will contain both source-code and executable of specific platform;

Now we should mount the X_merged directory as volume to the Docker container for building the source code for each platform

For i386:

```
 sudo docker run --privileged -v /home/viswesn/i386_merged/:/source-code -it ubuntu-trusty:14:01 /bin/bash
```

For amd64:

```
sudo docker run --privileged -v /home/viswesn/amd64_merged/:/source-code -it ubuntu-amd64:14:01 /bin/bash
```

With this, the same source code is build simultaneously for all the platform parallel'ly without multiple copies of source-code.