# How do multiple containers access the directory in other container

Tags: docker, kubernetes

How do multiple containers(create from same image) access the directory(packaged in the image) in other container? There are some ways not elegant:

1. Mount directory into a shared volume or host path. When a container changed files in the directory, other containers will perceive it. Is there any idea to make shared volume working like copy-on-write?
2. Create a volume for each container, and copy directory into the volume. In this way, the directory have to save multiple copies in disk.

I've browsed this problem [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550736/can-i-mount-docker-host-directory-as-copy-on-write-overlay], I don't want containers to run in privileged mode. Is there a better idea?

Comment: You can `COPY --from` files from arbitrary images in your Dockerfiles.  The various volume-oriented tricks you see in pure-Docker setups won't work well in Kubernetes; it's hard to get a ReadWriteMany volume, and Kubernetes won't automatically put files into volumes for you.  Do you _need_ shared files, or can you use a database or some other mechanism?

Comment: Does this work at image build time or at container run time?

Answer (score 3):

Per design one container cannot access the files inside another container.
You will need to store the data outside of a container, then mount it via [volume mount or bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). Alternatively you could try to perform some NFS/SMB/... mount of shared storage inside the container.

This is completely independent from running a container in host mode.